# How could i remove or delete elements from LWC

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lightning-experience

I know how to create child nodes in lwc using innerHTML but if I want to remove it, what will be the way?

Comment: Give it a unique class name and delete that? You might not be able to find it using this.template.querySelectorAll... maybe use the this.querySelectorAll instead?

Comment: Generally speaking you should use conditionally rendered parts directly in the template using ```<template if:true={someTrackedProperty}>```. Messing directly with the DOM in the component's javascript can lead to unexpected results/misbehaviour.